# How to push specific elements of JSON response into array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, object

I am working with the Nomics cryptocurrency API. Here is the Axios call:

```
axios.get(apiURL + apiKey + apiSpecs)
.then(function (response) {
  // sort data by highest market cap
  console.log(response.data)
})
```

And corresponding JSON response:

```
[{ circulating_supply: '70126880',
    high: '7.18687000',
    high_timestamp: '2018-01-05T00:00:00.000Z',
    market_cap: '58767727.57',
    max_supply: '100000000',
    price: '0.83802000',
    price_date: '2019-04-08',
    currency: 'ETP',
    rank: '96' },
  { circulating_supply: '350000000',
    high: '2.83125000',
    high_timestamp: '2018-01-10T00:00:00.000Z',
    market_cap: '54558000.00',
    max_supply: null,
    price: '0.15588000',
    price_date: '2019-04-08',
    currency: 'QASH',
    rank: '97' }, 
... ]
```

How can I return an array of just the currency attributes such as `var arr = [ETP, QASH, ...]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Comment: `const myArrayData = response.data.map(data => data.currency);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map`:

```js
const response = [{
    circulating_supply: '70126880',
    high: '7.18687000',
    high_timestamp: '2018-01-05T00:00:00.000Z',
    market_cap: '58767727.57',
    max_supply: '100000000',
    price: '0.83802000',
    price_date: '2019-04-08',
    currency: 'ETP',
    rank: '96'
  },
  {
    circulating_supply: '350000000',
    high: '2.83125000',
    high_timestamp: '2018-01-10T00:00:00.000Z',
    market_cap: '54558000.00',
    max_supply: null,
    price: '0.15588000',
    price_date: '2019-04-08',
    currency: 'QASH',
    rank: '97'
  }
];

const currencies = response.map(({ currency }) => currency);
console.log(currencies);
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var response = [{
    circulating_supply: '70126880',
    high: '7.18687000',
    high_timestamp: '2018-01-05T00:00:00.000Z',
    market_cap: '58767727.57',
    max_supply: '100000000',
    price: '0.83802000',
    price_date: '2019-04-08',
    currency: 'ETP',
    rank: '96'
  },
  {
    circulating_supply: '350000000',
    high: '2.83125000',
    high_timestamp: '2018-01-10T00:00:00.000Z',
    market_cap: '54558000.00',
    max_supply: null,
    price: '0.15588000',
    price_date: '2019-04-08',
    currency: 'QASH',
    rank: '97'
  }
];

var currencies = response.map(function(item) {
  return item.currency;
});
console.log(currencies);
```